# Is there a workflow to update a Netbeans 7.0.1 project using Swing to use Netbeans 7.4?

Tags: netbeans

*(I'm new to Netbeans and my Java experience is rudimentary and limited to using Processing with Eclipse, so this may be a very basic question.)*

I am working with an open source project which was developed using NetBeans 7.0.1 for gui stuff. The project will load and run in NetBeans 7.4 but the GUI is not editable. Is there some workflow to update the GUI? I don't want to rebuild it from scratch but I would like to use the latest version of NetBeans.

The error msg I get is below. I suspect I face rebuilding.

[image]

Comment: Well, `Swing` itself is not discontinued. Just that particular type of project. You might try closing the project and then creating a "new project with existing sources" and seeing if it lets you create a new project on top of your old one.

Comment: @ryvantage - thanks. I tried that but getting an error msg saying "Package folder already used in Project" with additional verbiage that the folders I selected are already used in another project - "owned by" - the open source project I am trying to work with. Guess I will stick with NB 7.0.1 rather than muck around with IDE arcana

Comment: Try copy/pasting the `src` folder into a new folder and try again. The `src` folder only contains the `.java` and `.form` files (the `.form` files are really just `xml` files that the GUI builder uses).